# how do I loop around a coroutine pipeline

Tags: python, coroutine

In the following python script, I have 3 handler coroutines that simulate a deeper chain of responsibility system. **This is all being done without the use of the Asyncio module**.

Each handler is receiving a list of two ints (ex: [1, 5]) and decides weather to handle the list or pass it to the next handler. The last handler in the line will modify the list and then can decide to send it back to the first handler.
This is my current issue as I don't know how to fully implement the loop.

Here's my current implementation of it:

```
import functools

#typical coroutine implementation
def coroutine(function):
    @functools.wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        generator = function(*args, **kwargs)
        next(generator)
        return generator

    return wrapper

@coroutine
def Handler_04(successor):
    while True:
        num = yield
        if num[0] in range(0, 4):
            print("Handler_04 will handle it!")
            return
        else:
            successor.send(num)


@coroutine
def Handler_59(successor):
    while True:
        num = yield
        if num[0] in range(0, 4):
            print("Handler_04 will handle it!")
            return
        else:
            successor.send(num)


@coroutine
def Handler_gt9(successor):
    while True:
        num = yield
        print("Reached Handler_gt9")
        num[0] = num[0] - num[1]
        if num[0] < 0 or not isinstance(num[0], int):
            print("Can't do")
            return
        else:
            successor.send(num)

first = none
third = Handler_gt9(first)
second = Handler_59(third)
first = Handler_04(second)

#this function should handle a list of lists (ex: [[0, 5],[5, 7],[12, 4]....]
def handler_chain(list=[]):
    for num in list:
        first.send(num)
```

Of course, the code above won't work: you can't just

```
first = None
third = Handler_gt9(first)
[...]
first = Handler_04(second)
```

Looking online I found Beazle's explanation of coroutines in python 2.5. Unfortunately, do to my poor knowledge of programming, I'm unable to follow all of it, but I know it states that when building a pipelines, there must be a sink point where the pipeline ends. Unfortunately he doesn't provide an answer for my case, and I'm genuinely a bit lost.

The only way to be able to implement the loop at this point, I think, would be by accepting Handler_gt9 as the sink and have handler_chain somehow extract num from Handler_gt9 and decide weather or not to send it back to the pipeline. I'm unaware of how implement it.

Comment: `none` is a Python command, you should use `None`. _"Of course, the code above won't work:"_ could you post the error traceback?

Comment: Is there a copy-paste error with the coroutine identifiers and their parameter (`first`, 'second`')? It seems cyclic

Comment: instead of a _sink_ you could define a global list, `[[0, 5],[5, 7],[12, 4]....]`, and the last handler will update the list. Iterating over list which change size is not "good" so use a `while list:` or similar